# Java copy a folder excluding some internal file

Tags: java, copy, directory

I have a folder with this structure

mainFolder

```
   --Sub1  
         --File .scl
         --File .awl
         --Other files
   --Sub2  
         --Files
   --Sub3
   --Sub4
```

I want to copy it to another location but i want the Sub3 to be avoided and (depending from the situation) some file from the Sub1

Here is an extract from what i did so far:

```
FileUtils.copyDirectory(srcDir, dstDir, new FileFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File pathname) {
            // We don't want 'Sub3' folder to be imported
            // + look at the settings to decide if some format needs to be
            // excluded
            String[] ignoreList= new String[]{
                    !Settings.getSiemensOptionAWL() ? ".awl":"uselessStringWilNeverBeFound",
                    !Settings.getSiemensOptionSCL() ? ".scl":"uselessStringWilNeverBeFound",
                    "Sub3"
            };

            return !(ignoreFile(pathname, ignoreList) && pathname
                    .isDirectory());
        }
    }, true);


    public static boolean ignoreFile(File file, String[] ignoreList) {
        for (final String ignoreStr : ignoreList)
            if (file.getAbsolutePath().contains(ignoreStr))
                return true;
        return false;
    }
```

Apparently it seams to work. But i think is a very ugly solution....
Does anyone knows a better way?

P.S:
of course Settings.getSiemensOptionAWL() is just boolean function taht return my decision

Comment: It might be easy to copy the entire directory to the new location, then delete the files (from that copy) that shouldn't be there.  Obviously this won't be appropriate if the motive is security-related rather than the base functionality.

Comment: I see what do you mean... but immagine yo do not what the user have the risk of copying data that you do not what the user to have. ( thi is not the case but i want to have a clean suolution) :)

Comment: even... apparently sometimes it works but sometime it does not... maybe there is just a better way to the same thinks!

Comment: even... better if i update... it seams to work but i want a better solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The other options suggested here are good, however another alternative is to nest multiple simpler FileFilters together (which may be overkill, of course!)

```
public class FailFastFileFilter implements FileFilter {
    protected final List<FileFilter> children = new ArrayList<FileFilter>();

    public FailFastFileFilter(FileFilter... filters) {
        for (FileFilter filter: filters) {
            if (filter != null)
                this.filters.add(filter);
        }       
    }

    public boolean accept(File pathname) {
        for (FileFilter filter: this.filters) {
            if (!filter.accept(pathname)) {
                return false; // fail on the first reject
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Then simply combine short, concise FileFilters for the Sub3 case, the .scl and the .awl case. The example FailFastFileFilter I've shown above would let you specify null as one of the filters (so you could use inline if statements to determine whether particular FileFilters are applied)

For the sake of completion, here's a general idea of how I'd implement the child filters for the Sub1 cases and the Sub3 case.

First, a filter to excluding files with a particular extension within a directory:

```
public class ExcludeExtensionInDirFileFilter implements FileFilter {
    protected final String parentFolder;
    protected final String extension;

    public ExtensionFileFilter(String parentFolder, String extension) {
        this.parentFolder = parentFolder;
        this.extension = extension.toLowerCase();
    }

    public boolean accept(File file) {
        if (!file.isDirectory() && file.getParentFile().getName().equalsIgnoreCase(parentFolder))
            return !file.getAbsolutePath().toLowerCase().endsWith(extension);
        else
            return true;
    }
}
```

Then to exclude a directory:

```
public class ExcludeDirFileFilter implements FileFilter {
    protected final String name;

    public ExcludeDirFileFilter(String name) {
        this.name = name.toLowerCase();
    }

    public boolean accept(File file) {
        if (file.isDirectory() && file.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name))
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
}
```

Setting up the FailFastFileFilter would then look something like:

```
FileFilter filters = new FailFastFileFilter(
    new ExcludeDirFileFilter("Sub3"), // always exclude Sub3
    (!Settings.getSiemensOptionAWL() ? new ExcludeExtensionInDirFileFilter("Sub1",".awl"), null), // Exclude Sub1/*.awl if desired
    (!Settings.getSiemensOptionSCL() ? new ExcludeExtensionInDirFileFilter("Sub1",".scl"), null) // Exclude Sub1/*.scl if desired
);

FileUtils.copyDirectory(srcDir, dstDir, filters);
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the ugliness comes from introducing `ignoreFile()`, which necessarily loses some of the useful information (which strings actually matter, which strings are file extensions, etc.) Additionally, that array is going to be created for every file in your hierarchy, which is extremely inefficient. Consider something like this, instead:

```
FileUtils.copyDirectory(srcDir, dstDir, new FileFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File pathname) {
        // We don't want 'Sub3' folder to be imported
        // + look at the settings to decide if some format needs to be
        // excluded
        String name = pathname.getName();
        if (!Settings.getSiemensOptionAWL() && name.endsWith(".awl"))
            return false;
        if (!Settings.getSiemensOptionSCL() && name.endsWith(".scl"))
            return false;

        return !(name.equals("Sub3") && pathname.isDirectory());
    }
}, true);
```

Comment: This is a clean solution but i think the first term after the return should have been !name.equals("Sub3") instead of !pathName.equals("Sub3").

Answer (score 1):

Is the case of those string fixed in stone?  Maybe something like

```
new FileFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File pathname) {
        String path = pathname.getAbsolutePath().toLowerCase();

        return (!pathname.isDirectory() || path.endsWith("sub3")) &&
            (!Settings.getSiemensOptionAWL() && path.endsWith(".awl")) &&
            (!Settings.getSiemensOptionSCL() && path.endsWith(".scl"));
    }
}
```

Comment: it looks nicer this way but my String are not fixed... they depends from the software settings...

Comment: just going off your code/description.  Maybe you what to use the decorator/chain of responsibility pattern to construct a variable filter make up of smaller, config specifc file filters.

Comment: Something along the lines of Peter's answer!

Answer (score -1):

Looks pretty clean to me. Just don't put all that directly in the calling code so you don't have to look at it all the time. Make your own CopySubDir class that hides all this code and provides a simple to understand interface to it. Then the calling code will look clean.