# Copy all subfolders from one to another except some subfolders in java?

Tags: java

I want to copy all subfolders from input folder to outputDir except some subfolders. The method i am using for copy is here. but i don't know how to filter the subfolders.

```
public static void copyDirectory(String inputFolder, String outputDir) {
            File source = new File(inputFolder);
            File desc = new File(outputDir);
            try {
                FileUtils.copyDirectory(source, desc);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Possible dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7191635/java-copy-a-folder-excluding-some-internal-file

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7191635/java-copy-a-folder-excluding-some-internal-file

Answer (score 1):

Hi use the following code:

```
public static void copyDirectory(String inputFolder, String outputDir) {
    File source = new File(inputFolder);
    File desc = new File(outputDir);

    ArrayList al=new ArrayList();//contains all your directory filter names
    try {

        for (File file : source.listFiles()) {
            if (!al.contains(file.getName())&&file.isDirectory()) {
                FileUtils.copyDirectory(source, desc);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: i have try your code but its not working because you are using   FileUtils.copyDirectory(source, desc); and this will copy all the data from source dir to desc dir

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public static void copyDirectory(String inputFolder, String outputDir) {

        File source = new File(inputFolder);
        File desc = new File(outputDir);
        String name = source.getName();
        String desti = desc.getPath() + "/" + name;
        File destination = new File(desti);
        destination.mkdir();
        File[] subFolders = source.listFiles();
        for (File subFolder : subFolders) {
             if (condition satisfies){
                 // copy to destination folder
             } else {
                 // Ignore
             }

        }

    }
```